# If statement triggered by button click

Tags: c#

Here is my code:

```cs
public static string name;
private void openWindow(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (button_name1.PerformClick){
        name = "name1";
    }
    if (button_name2.PeformClick)
    {
        name = "name2";
    }
    else
    {
        name = "name3";
    }
    this.Hide();
    Form2 form2 = new Form2();
    form2.ShowDialog();      
}
```

So I have three buttons, each of them should open a new identical window when it is clicked. But each button has to save a different name in a string (name).

My goal in this `if` condition is exactly that, but VS2017 says PeformClick cannot be converted to the type bool.

Second, it means that button doesn't have a definition for PeformClick.

How can I solve this?

Or have I tried it completely wrong from the beginning?

Comment: You should handle "Click" events for each text box and possible call a method to open the new form. `button_name1.Click += button_name1_Click;` and implement button_name1_Click (and others) as event handlers (object sender, EventArgs e)

Comment: _"have I tried it completely wrong from the beginning?"_ -- probably. For one, the `PerformClick()` member of the `Button` class is a _method_, but you are trying to use it as if it were a `bool` property. For another, your second `if` statement is trying to access `PeformClick`, not `PerformClick`, and that definitely doesn't even exist at all. But the biggest warning sign is your `static string name` field. It's not clear what you're doing with that field, but you shouldn't be using a field to pass data from one method to another, never mind a `static` field.

Comment: All that said, you haven't provided enough context for anyone to provide a good answer. If you really want to go down this road, you'll need to improve the question. Please see [mcve] and [ask].

Comment: Extract code from button handler into a separate method returning in. Now you can call it from button click event handler and from `openWindow` method.

Comment: @OguzOzgul - I'd avoid creating event handlers for each button. That's just tedious.

Comment: @Sinatr - I don't understand what you're saying?

Comment: @Enigmativity you're right, the part of the code where he attaches the openWindow to the button click events is not there, so I just thought he was trying to achieve something by just adding this method. Of course all click events can invoke this same method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this "openWindow" attached as click-handler to all three buttons? Then "sender" is that specific button, you just need to cast it. You could set the [.Tag](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.tag?view=netcore-3.1#System_Windows_Forms_Control_Tag) property beforehand and read its value in the handler.

```
private void openWindow(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Button clickedButton = (Button)sender;
    name = clickedButton.Tag;

    // create form etc
}
```

Comment: *"Is this "openWindow" attached as click-handler to all three buttons?"* - no. If it would be yes, then code make no sense (it will cause stackoverflow excepton).

Comment: @Sinatr - What are you saying? There's no chance of a stack overflow here.

Comment: @janne Glad to help. But do mind the concerns about "name" being a static field, there may be better ways of passing values

Comment: @Enigmativity, sorry, in my head it was a clear picture of OP is performing clicks of other buttons in the click event handler of some "open form" button. I was wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have tree buttons and all of their click event is attached to `openWindow`
something below can work for you.

```
public static string name;
private void openWindow(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Button senderButton = (Button)sender;
    if (senderButton == button1)
    {
        name = "name1";
    }
    else if (senderButton == button2)
    {
        name = "name2";
    }
    else
    {
        name = "name3";
    }
    this.Hide();
    Form form2 = new Form();
    form2.ShowDialog();
}
```

Actually this is the complete code of the approach which is also offered by @Hans Keﬆing.